# Can't compile Audacity from source on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: audacity

Trying to build **Audacity v2.4.2** on **Ubuntu 20.04** from source.

Following instructions from http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Building_On_Linux

What I've done so far:

- Installed all dependencies
- Cloned and built wxwidgets 3.1.3 with gtk2
- Tested wxwidget with samples - minimal and widgets (all good)

```
$ /opt/newbie_2021/wxWidgets/buildgtk/samples/widgets/widgets
```

[image: wxwidget sample: widget UI]

- wx-config output:

```
newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ wx-config --version
3.1.3
newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ wx-config --list

    Default config is gtk2-unicode-3.1

  Default config will be used for output
```

- Cloned audacity

**Issue**:

When I'm running -

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -Daudacity_use_ffmpeg=loaded ..`

I get this output:

```
newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:/opt/newbie_2021/audacity/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -Daudacity_use_ffmpeg=loaded --log-level=TRACE ..
-- The ASM_NASM compiler identification is unknown
-- Didn't find assembler
-- Build Info:
--   Host System: Linux-5.4.0-58-generic
--   Host System Name: Linux
--   Host System Processor: x86_64
--   Host System Version: 5.4.0-58-generic
--   Host System Architecture: 64-bit
-- 
--   Compiler: /usr/bin/c++
--   Compiler Version: 9.3.0
--   Compiler Standard: 14
--   Compiler Standard Required: ON
--   Compiler Extensions: 
-- 
--   Current Commit: f7c0ba837
-- 
-- ========== Configuring wxwidgets ==========
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(167): wxWidgets_FIND_COMPONENTS : adv;base;core;html;net;qa;xml
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(167): wxWidgets_SELECT_OPTIONS=--static=no;--unicode=no;--universal=no
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_CXX_FLAGS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_DEFINITIONS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_CXX_FLAGS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets required components : adv;base;core;html;net;qa;xml
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets optional components : 
wxWidgets_LIBRARIES=
wxWidgets_LIBRARY_DIRS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_LIBRARIES=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_LIBRARY_DIRS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_CXX_FLAGS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_DEFINITIONS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_CXX_FLAGS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets required components : adv;base;core;html;net;qa;xml
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets optional components : 
wxWidgets_LIBRARIES=
wxWidgets_LIBRARY_DIRS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_LIBRARIES=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(171): wxWidgets_LIBRARY_DIRS=
-- /opt/newbie_2021/audacity/cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake(167): _wx_filename:  _wx_filename-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at cmake-proxies/cmake-modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:1046 (message):
  wxWidgets wx/version.h file not found in .
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake-proxies/wxWidgets/CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package)
 
 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/opt/newbie_2021/audacity/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/opt/newbie_2021/audacity/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

**More info**:

```
newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ wx-config --cxxflags
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
```

```
newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ wx-config --libs
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1
```

```
newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ which wx-config
/usr/local/bin/wx-config
```

```
newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ ll /usr/local/bin/wx-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Dec 31 16:00 /usr/local/bin/wx-config -> /usr/local/lib/wx/config/gtk2-unicode-3.1
```

```
newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ /opt/newbie_2021/wxWidgets/buildgtk/wx-config --version
3.1.3
```

```
newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ ll /opt/newbie_2021/wxWidgets/buildgtk/wx-config 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 newbie_2021 wireshark 38 Dec 31 15:56 /opt/newbie_2021/wxWidgets/buildgtk/wx-config -> lib/wx/config/inplace-gtk2-unicode-3.1
```

**Update 1**:
Thanks to @Naglfar on #audacity who is helping me with this.

The first issue I can see is that "[Build on Linux](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Building_On_Linux)" document is missing `make` command for wxwidgets build.

Secondly, I had to explicitly specify the target location:
`../configure --with-cxx=14 --with-gtk=2 **--prefix=/usr/local**`

I'm still getting the same error for `cmake` in audacity but at least there is some progress.

```
newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ wx-config --cxxflags
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread

newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ wx-config --selected-config
gtk2-unicode-3.1

newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ wx-config --libs
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1

newbie_2021@msig7-ubuntu:~$ find /usr/local/ -name version.h
/usr/local/lib/wx/version.h
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/version.h
```

**Update 2**:

Finally got it resolved. I had to delete the cmake cache file.
`CMakeCache.txt`

After that `cmake` ran fine, as did `make` and `make install`.

Comment: something is wrong here. Can you run `wx-config --cxxflags` and `wx-config --libs`? It is also preferable to post the output in the question as pastebin links become outdated.

Comment: @Igor Just added that info in the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `wxwidgets` run configure with `--prefix=/usr/local`.

Run `make` before running `make install`.

Then `ldconfig`.

Delete `CMakeCache.txt` and then run `cmake` in *audacity/build*.